# Find minimum of integral with two variable terms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, mathematical-optimization

I wanted to see an approach to solving this problem with Mathematica: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723531/how-would-you-attack-this-problem

Determine real numbers a and b so that the integral is as small as possible.

$$\int_0^1 \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) - (ax + b)\right]^2 dx$$

I used a brute force approach where I find the integral first and then find the minimum as

```
  Integrate[(-b - a*x + (1 + x^2)^(-1))^2, {x, 0, 1}]

  Minimize[a^2/3 + (1/8)*(2 + 8*b^2 + Pi - 4*b*Pi) + a*(b - Log[2]), {a, b}]
```

This resulted in

$$a\to \log (64)-\frac{3 \pi }{2},b\to \pi -\log (8)$$

What I am wondering is if there a slicker way to do this in Mathematica in case there is not an easy closed-form solution to the integral perhaps using [*FindMinimum*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it in a more numerical way is this:

```
FindMinimum[
 Inactive[NIntegrate][(-b - a*x + (1 + x^2)^(-1))^2, {x, 0, 1}],
 {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}
]
```

The advantage is that it will work even when the integral has no nice closed form.

Another method that is sometimes useful is to rephrase the problem using `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {y'[x] == (-b - a*x + (1 + x^2)^(-1))^2, y[0] == 0},
  y[1],
  {x, 0, 1},
  {a, b}
]
FindMinimum[sol[a, b], {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]
```

Comment: I would have never thought of that second approach. Thanks!